# EPPlus Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT)

Tags: c#, excel

Como acceder a un archivo excel mediante EPPlus?
El codigo parece estar bien..

```
   ViewBag.Message = "Cargar Almuerzos";
        byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MENÚ DEL 09 AL 13 DE MAYO.xls");
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file);
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
        {
            if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count == 0)
            {
                string error = "Your Excel file does not contain any work sheets";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Has hecho algunas pruebas con EPPlus? Puedes pasarte a ver este [link de SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738123/using-epplus-with-a-memorystream). Alguien parecía tener tu mismo problema pero tenia el archivo excel vacio, también te recomendaría usar otro nombre para tu `.xls`, aunque si no te da problemas, no hay que cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Porque le pasas un byte[] en lugar de asignar directo el archivo por medio del `FileInfo`

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\MENÚ DEL 09 AL 13 DE MAYO.xls");
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count == 0)
    {
        string error = "Your Excel file does not contain any work sheets";
    }
}
```

Tambien intenta asignar un xls sin espacio ni caracteres especiales como ser el acento sobre la U, en el nombre del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la impresión que el problema está en los espacios en el nombre del archivo. Intenta cambiar el nombre o ponerlo entre [].